Adjustments with the gsummary package for regression tables in R
I want to create a regression table for a publication. I have fixed effects, and have used "feols" "fixest". How can I create a table with significance stars with gtsummary and modify so that I can change certain words to Norwegian translation, adjust for language? I also want to include fixed effects details in the table, such as tick marks.
I have looked into  add_significance_stars(), but not tried it.I have seen that language specification is possible, but not sure how. Are there any examples out there?
